# How to make a correct time calculation?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an MySQl table with different fields.

```
Date       Time_in  Time_out Break
2013-12-16 06:00:00 16:30:00 01:15:00
```

I am able to calculate the time diffrence (10:30) between Time-in and Time_out with

```
TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(Time-in, Time_out),'%H:%i') AS pers_in
```

How do I get the real working time with the time of the break calculated?
I have tried

```
$worked= date('H:i', strtotime($row['pers_in']) - strtotime($row['Break']));
```

This wil give an working time of 10:15 instead of 9:15.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @MarkReed `Time_out - Time_in - Break` = 9:15

Comment: `TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(Time_out, Time_in), Break),'%H:%i') AS game` ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16ed76/1

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yeah... This is more easy to understand.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you should submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work in the SQL?

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(Time_in, Time_out), Break), '%H:%i')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply subtract the three times to get the correct value;

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time_out - time_in - break, '%H:%i') working_time
FROM Table1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16ed76/2).